# How to check if a specific link has been clicked(JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I'm making a chrome extension and what I want to happen is to alert the user if a specific link has been clicked on Facebook. And in my script every time I click a link it always alert accessing gma.

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    //this == the link that was clicked
       var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (window.location.protocol == 'https:'){
        if(href == "gmanetwork"){
            alert("Accessing Gma");
        }}
    else{
        alert("false");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code at Question assigns the value `if (window.location.protocol = 'https:'){` `"gmanetwork"` to `href` using `=` operator at

```
if (href = "gmanetwork")
```

instead of checking the values for equality, use `===` operator

```
if (window.location.protocol === 'https:') {
    if (href === "gmanetwork") {
        alert("Accessing Gma");
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, you used an alternative appropriate operator `==` at comment `//this == the link that was clicked`

Comment: it doesn't alert the user anymore after adding the === operator

Comment: @Babyz `$(this).attr("href")` returns the full URL. You can check for a specific set of characters using `String.prototype.indexOf()` or `RegExp.prototype.test()` `if (href.indexOf("gmanetwork") !== -1)` , `if (/gmanetwork/.test(href))` or use the full URL `if (href === "https://path/to/gmanetwork")`

Comment: I tried this (href.indexOf("gmanetwork") !== -1) and it works well. I'm new to this but what does -1 means?

Comment: See [String.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) _"Return value
The index of the first occurrence of the specified value; -1 if not found."_ ,
 [Non-identity / strict inequality (!==)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Non-identity_strict_inequality_(!)) _"Non-identity / strict inequality (!==)
The non-identity operator returns true if the operands are not equal and/or not of the same type."_

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest something like this:

You change your html links to :

```
<a href="http://yourlink" targetLink="GMA Network"> Your link </a>
```

and your script:

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    if($(this).attr("targetLink"){
        alert("You are going to the following page: " + $(this).attr("targetLink"));
    }
});
```

Comment: But what I want is that if the user clicked the link, for example, the user clicked the link then it will alert the user that he's accessing gmanetwork site

Comment: well, you can add an attribute to your link, like :
<a href="http://somewhere" targetPlace="GMA Network"> link </a>
and (...) ok it is hard to write this in a comment. I update my answer